# Custom title bar with Image view for TabActivity

Tags: android

Dear all I am using following code to create the custom title with image view.But it shows the null pointer exception for the imageview. How to solve this ?

```
    public class MyCustomTab2Activity extends TabActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
                    //Tab Content
        setContentView(R.layout.my_tab_home);       
        ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_logout);         
        imag.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
        });
                    //custom title bar content
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.logintitle); 

        ......


        ...........


    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried your code. I'm also getting nullpointer exception. Just try my updated answer. Was that useful or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in your `TabHost` main Activity -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header);

    image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(CustomWindowTitle.this, "This is sample", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**Window_title.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:background="#323331">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/header" 
    android:src="@drawable/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this can be helpful for you. See my output below -

[image: CustomWindowTitle]

**Update**

I got it. You're declared your custom title after the image's `OnclickListener` Make the changes in your code like below -

```
public class MyCustomTab2Activity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
                //Tab Content
    setContentView(R.layout.my_tab_home);       

    //custom title bar content
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.logintitle); 

    ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_logout);         
    imag.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    });

    ......


    ...........


}

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` is not really designed to be used in this way, there are two things you could try. Set the following flag on you `ImageView` , `imag.setFocusable=(true)` and see if that works, or instead try using an `ImageButton`, or just a `Button` with the `background` property set to your image, as it's designed to be used in this way.